# Websockets with multiple datas in onMessage annotation

Tags: java, websocket

I am using websockets. I want to use multiple @onMessage overloaded methods with different data types.
In Client side i a have the following methods

```
   @OnMessage
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    System.out.println(message.getContent()+":"+message.getSubject());
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Where Message is pojo class and decoded and encoded it.

In server side

```
   @OnMessage
public void onMessage(String msg, Session session) {
    try {

        System.out.println("Receive Message:" + msg);

        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("{\"subject\":\"This is subject1\",\"content\":\"This is content1\"}");
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("This is Example Test");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Class: clientwebsocket.MyClient. Text MessageHandler already registered.

at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ErrorCollector.composeComprehensiveException(ErrorCollector.java:83)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$1.run(ClientManager.java:384)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:565)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:110)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:343)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:182)
at clientwebsocket.ClientWebSocket.start(ClientWebSocket.java:31)
at clientwebsocket.ClientWebSocket.main(ClientWebSocket.java:40)
```

can any one suggest us how to use multiple types of data sending to/from the server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible. [JSR 356](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356) defines clearly that there can be only one message handler per text message, one per binary message and one per [PongMessage](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/PongMessage.html). See [@OnMessage](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/OnMessage.html) javadoc:

======

This method level annotation can be used to make a Java method receive incoming web socket messages. Each websocket
 endpoint may only have one message handling method for each of the native websocket message formats: text, binary and pong. Methods
 using this annotation are allowed to have
 parameters of types described below, otherwise the container will generate an error at deployment time.

The allowed parameters are:

1. Exactly one of any of the following choices

   - if the method is handling text messages:

     - [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to receive the whole message
     - Java primitive or class equivalent to receive the whole message converted to that type
     - [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and boolean pair to receive the message in parts
     - [java.io.Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) to receive the whole message as a blocking stream
     - any object parameter for which the endpoint has a text decoder ([Decoder.Text](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/Decoder.Text.html) or
        [Decoder.TextStream](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/Decoder.TextStream.html)).
   - if the method is handling binary messages:

     - byte[] or [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to receive the whole message
     - byte[] and boolean pair, or [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) and boolean pair to receive the message in parts
     - [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) to receive the whole message as a blocking stream
     - any object parameter for which the endpoint has a binary decoder ([Decoder.Binary](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/Decoder.Binary.html) or
        [Decoder.BinaryStream](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/Decoder.BinaryStream.html)).
   - if the method is handling pong messages:

     - [PongMessage](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/PongMessage.html) for handling pong messages
2. and Zero to n String or Java primitive parameters
    annotated with the [javax.websocket.server.PathParam](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/server/PathParam.html) annotation for server endpoints.
3. and an optional [Session](https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.4/javax/websocket/Session.html) parameter

The parameters may be listed in any order.

The method may have a non-void return type, in which case the web socket
 runtime must interpret this as a web socket message to return to the peer. 
 The allowed data types for this return type, other than void, are String, 
 ByteBuffer, byte[], any Java primitive or class equivalent, and anything for 
 which there is an encoder. If the method uses a Java primitive as a return 
 value, the implementation must construct the text message to send using the 
 standard Java string representation of the Java primitive unless there developer
 provided encoder for the type configured for this endpoint, in which
 case that encoder must be used. If the method uses 
 a class equivalent of a Java primitive as a return value, the implementation 
 must construct the text message from the Java primitive equivalent as 
 described above.

Developers should
 note that if developer closes the session during the invocation of a method with a return type, e method will complete but the
 return value will not be delivered to the remote endpoint. The send failure will be passed back into the endpoint's error handling method.

For example:

```
 @OnMessage
 public void processGreeting(String message, Session session) {
     System.out.println("Greeting received:" + message);
 }
```

For example:

```
 @OnMessage
 public void processUpload(byte[] b, boolean last, Session session) {
     // process partial data here, which check on last to see if these is more on the way
 }
```

Developers should not continue to reference message objects of type [java.io.Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html),  [java.nio.ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)
 or [java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) after the annotated method has completed, since they
 may be recycled by the implementation.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting a similar exception in the following situation. I have endpoint class and it defines a text onMessage handler. I have inherited a new class from it, annotated it as a server endpoint and specified a different text onMessage handler. Why parent class onMessage handler is considered in conflict?